# Combine an audio and a text file as one single file

Tags: file, audio, text, format, wavesurfer.js

Is there a way to combine an audio file (either `.mp3` or `.wav`) and store some text information in a `.txt` file and save it as one single file (in which format such a file would be, I am not sure).

**Edit**: Providing some context on what exactly I need to do.
I am using Wavesurfer.js. Say I have an audio file using which I want to make regions. Those regions are stored in a text file which contains 3 values, i.e `start` and `end` times of regions in the audio along with a `label` for the region. I want to store the information in the text file saved with the audio in a manner that when a user loads an audio file using `wavesurfer.load()`, the regions get created automatically. How can i do so? Is this even possible?

Comment: MP3 format can have text and image metadata stored in its ID3tag field

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to store your .txt file content into the [ID3 metadata container](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ID3). You can, for example, store it under `UNSYNCEDLYRICS` field.